# Why does spring dependencies on Maven Central differ from actual local?

Tags: spring-boot, maven

I am using `spring-boot-starter-parent 2.3.9.RELEASE` which according to [Maven Central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-security/2.3.9.RELEASE) should give me `spring-boot-starter-security 2.3.9.RELEASE` which in turn should give me `spring-security-config 5.3.8.RELEASE`.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

However, when I look at Eclipse I see `spring-security-config 5.3.5.RELEASE`. I dont understand why my local is not reflecting `spring-security-config 5.3.8.RELEASE` for this artifact even though spring boot starter parent and spring boot starter security (both parents of this) are correctly showing 2.3.9.RELEASE. Also I'm not sure I understand what "Managed from 5.3.8.RELEASE" means in the screenshot. Could someone assist ?
[image]

Comment: First the given link does not point to Maven Central this is: https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.3.9.RELEASE/pom  second you must have somewhere overwriting some of the deps..either directly or indirectly via an other bom or maybe another dependencies. But without your full pom file it's impossible to answer that correctly...Apart from that I would ask why not use the most recent version of spring boot? (2.4.3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that an entry in your `<dependencyManagement>` section of the POM overrode the version.

This may be a direct entry or a BOM, which you recognise by `<scope>import</scope>`.

Comment: thanks - it was a dependencyManagement issue that was overriding others